# Alpha blend Materials on top of each other randomly disappearing

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I have several Alpha Blend elements, layed on top of each other on three different levels.
My problem is that the elements on the middle level are disappearing sometimes, corresponding the the limit of the alpha of the further level.

It's a bit hard to explain, so here are some pictures to explain my issue:

[image: Elements on different levels as seen from the front]

[image: When I move the camera slightly to the side, the round element suddenly disappears]

[image: And it reappears when it's visually off the edge of the background element]

So you can see the round element is visible from the front, but disappear as soon as I move the camera to the side,and only reappears when it's visually off the edge of the background element, if that makes sense. Same for the green text above, wich is on the second layer of elements as well.

I wanted to post GIFs as well, but for some reason I can't upload them directly, so here are the links: https://i.gyazo.com/156e65c4255a87fcc7448c869d9236fa.gif

https://i.gyazo.com/874016be4b586e749cdfe0db87d08f81.gif

I hope you guys understand what my issue is and will be able to help me on that matter!

I'm using Eevee render, and the problem is the same in the Viewport and the Render.

Comment: Without analyzing the question thoroughly: it's probably about how alpha blend is layered based on origin positions: https://i.imgur.com/LQzSi87.gif - you may want to use alpha hashed or alpha clip instead.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, by changing the alpha mode, I lose transparency levels on my circular texture, which has several levels of opacity (several gray values) in its mask.
By doing alpha ashed, I get a pixellated effect whic I don't want, and alpha clip just makes everything either 100% transparent or 100% opaque, which I don't want either.

Comment: This is why you have 3 options to choose from, each with upsides and downsides... You could use a driver + geonodes to move the origins in such a way that objects remain ordered properly.